# How to convert AVI videos to small (smartphone) size

Tags: video, conversion, ffmpeg

I want to convert some `.avi` videos to a lower resolution, both to considerably shrink the files' sizes and to make them easily viewable on a smartphone. How can I do the conversion? I have ffmpeg installed on a desktop running Ubuntu.

Comment: I have tried a couple of suggested ffmpeg commands but they were all somehow faulty, apparently due to changes in ffmpeg syntax

Comment: Actually I just found a nice app which has a .deb and does the job well: http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverterDown.htm

Comment: MediaCoder is also very good, never used it for putting to smartphone, but have used it for many other things and it has tons of options. I didn't post it as I didn't know it had a .deb, I thought it was only available using Wine (which there is a walkthrough for setting up on the site).

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you download [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php), which is basically a nice (subjective!) interface which will allow you to convert between formats easily (including ffmpeg).

It includes presets for mobile devices and if you are uncomfortable using ffmpeg directly, you should like this program.

Comment: +1 Handbrake is nice, definitely worth the time to get if you don't have it already, useful for a lot of things.

Comment: William, I added Handbrake's ppa, and the lines to sources.list, but after update, it could not install it: 'E: Package handbrake has no installation candidate'. Any ideas?

Comment: @hnns - All I can say is that it is Ubuntu compatible, I do not know the specifics, nor am I an expert at Ubuntu - you are best off asking that specific question on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com